# How do i handle windows messages properly in c++

Tags: c++, windows, message

I am quite new to handling messages in c++ and after quite a bit of reading am still a bit confused.

In my program i am calculating some files crc32 values and use PeekMessage to check for messages in the queue. I am doing this so that the dialog can still be operated while the function is performing. The only problem i have is that when the messages are being received the crc32 function effectively pauses.

Is there anyway to continue to receive message (i.e. move the dialog) and continue to run the crc32 function at the same time.

The relevant code is.

```
CalculateCrc32Value()
{
    // Code to check crc32 value here.....

    // Check message queue.
    MSG uMsg;
    PeekMessage(&uMsg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE);
    TranslateMessage(&uMsg);
    DispatchMessage(&uMsg);
}
```

Comment: Move the crc32 code to a background thread and post a message back to your main thread when it is complete.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick answer, guess i better start reading more about threads then.